# Incorrect Icon in notification center

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app which receives the push notifications and display them even if screen is locked.
Icon shown in notification bar is not correct. My project is developed in flutter and app icon is working fine. Where exactly I need to keep the icon file to show correct icon on notification panel. Please refer image below.

[image]

Comment: You need check the assert with open by Xcode

Comment: @JerryZhou This screenshot is of one plus 7 pro. I am using visual studio to build app on windows machine.

Comment: You need check how to edit icon in flutter document website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding below code in your `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
<!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

For more read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Comment: @Ravindra, it should be at application level or activity level

Comment: Application-level. please [refer this to check official project's AndroidManifest](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/34ffee4430c4fcce994c4f38d7669a6a73617bfa/messaging/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L13-L22)

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and it worked for me:

1. Create a transparent and white notification icon (you can use the following tool: AndroidAssetStudio )

Download the zip folder, unzip and you'll see it contains a res folder with different drawable folders. Copy and paste the contents of the res folder in "android\app\src\main\res" path

2. Then open the AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following lines to it:

ic_stat_calendar_today is the name of my notification icon. And each of the drawable folders that have been pasted contain a different size of icon with the same name.

[image: Android Manifest]

3. If you want to change the color of the icon then check the above image. Add the metadata tag after the notification icon tag
4. Go to "android\app\src\main\res\values" and add a colors.xml file

[image: colors.xml]

```
<color name="colorAccent">#00FF00</color>
```

I have shared this answer in the following Github chain as well- [Solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17941#issuecomment-622268132).